# Adjacency Matrix of Sierprinski matrix

Tags: matrix, graphs-and-networks

how can i make adjacency matrix of sierprinski graphs?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe26

Answer (score 9):

```
ClearAll[meshF, edgesF, verticesF, coordsF, meshGraph]

meshF = DiscretizeGraphics @ Show[CantorMesh[#, 2], 
     RegionBoundary[RegionDifference[Rectangle[], 
        CantorMesh[#, 2]]] & /@ Range[#]] &;

verticesF = MeshCells[meshF[#], 0][[All, 1]] &;

edgesF = UndirectedEdge @@@ MeshCells[meshF[#], 1][[All, 1]] &;

coordsF = MeshCoordinates[meshF[#]] &;

meshGraph = Graph[verticesF@#, edgesF@#, VertexCoordinates -> coordsF[#], ##2] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
Row[meshGraph[#, ImageSize -> Small] & /@ Range[0, 2], Spacer[20]]
```

[image]

```
Row[meshGraph[#, ImageSize -> 1 -> (# + 1) 100, 
    VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
    VertexSize -> (1 + #)/5] & /@ Range[0, 2], Spacer[20]]
```

[image]

***Adjacency matrices:***

```
Row[ArrayPlot[AdjacencyMatrix[meshGraph@#], Mesh -> All, 
    ImageSize -> 300] & /@ Range[0, 2], Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

**Update:** An alternative approach successively re-scaling a `Rectangle` using `TransformedRegion` and `ScalingTransform`:

```
ClearAll[subDivide]
subDivide = # /. c_Polygon :> {c, 
      TransformedRegion[c, ScalingTransform[{1, 1}/3, #]] & /@ First[c]} &;
```

***Examples:***

```
Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[{Thin, Black}], 
  Nest[subDivide, Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}], 4]}]
```

[image]

```
polygons = Cases[
  Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[{Thin, Black}], 
    Nest[subDivide, Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}], 5]}],
  _Polygon, All]; 

Graphics[{RandomColor[], #} & /@ polygons,  ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Comment: if graph is given, how can i find adjacency matrix?

Comment: @MohitJames, you can use `AdjacencyMatrix[g]` if `g` is a `Graph` object.